# Error is displayed while clicking on file link to open

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, class

### while clicking on the file link to open the file, it is displaying an error as shown below

Unable to Access Page
The value of the "file" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

[Please find the screenshot of my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npaiK.png)
Apex Code--

```
public Attachwrapper(ContentDocument attach)
        {
            attachID = attach.id;
            attachmentName = attach.Title;----------------------this is the filed on ContentDocument to open a file
            //attachRecord = attach;
            List<String> descriptionList = new List<String>();
            if(!(String.isBlank(attach.description))){
                descriptionList = (attach.description).split(';');
                if(descriptionList.size() > 0){
                    docType = descriptionList[0];
                }
                if(descriptionList.size() > 1){
                    month = descriptionList[2];
                    year = descriptionList[2];
                }
            }
```

Lighning aura component block--

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.draftValues}" var="draftValue">
                    <tr>
                        <td 
                            class="slds-truncate"
                            style="word-wrap: break-word;"
                            data-label="{!draftValue.attachmentName}"
                            title="{!draftValue.attachmentName}"
                            >
                            <a href="{! '../../../../servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+draftValue.attachID}" target="_blank" tabindex="0">
                            {!draftValue.attachmentName}</a>----------this is the option to click 
                        </td>
```